# Why does Chrome Timeshow show Parse HTML events before Finish Loading?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, timeline, web-inspector

According to https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline

> Your recording should look something like the following. The
>   firstrecord (Send Request) is Chrome's HTTP request for the page,
>   followed by a Receive Response record for the corresponding HTTP
>   response, followed by one or more Receive Data records, a Finish
>   Loading record, and a Parse HTML record.

What I am seeing with the website that I am inspecting is

> Send Request (page)
>
> Receive Response (page)
>
> Receive Data (page)
>
> ...
>
> Receive Data (page)
>
> Parse HTML
>
> ...
>
> Parse HTML
>
> Send Request (assets)
>
> ...
>
> Send Request (assets)
>
> Receive Data (page)
>
> ...
>
> Receive Data (page)
>
> Finish Loading (page)

Under what circumstances would the browser start to parse HTML before finish loading?

Comment: I edited my original post to show all the Send Request events that come after the Parse HTML events for assets.

Comment: What is unclear about this? If the browser did not parse the HTML, then it would not even know what assets to load …

Comment: The unclear part is why the browser started to parse HTML before finish loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome (Blink actually) starts with parsing HTML as soon as "enough" data is received. This means that the "Parse HTML" event can happen (several times) before "Finish Loading (page)" is shown.

Comment: Thanks. Very concise answer.